# Android compilation error - transformJackWithJackForDebug

Tags: android, gradle

I have a problem when trying to build my android apps.
Anyone has an idea what it can be caused?

Message Gradle Build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.jack.Main with arguments {-D jack.dex.optimize=true -D jack.reporter=sdk -D jack.dex.debug.vars=true --classpath C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackRuntimeLibraries\debug\jars\8000\40\android-494676acc5ae561acdb3444fad9dc9c16dce108e.jar;C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackRuntimeLibraries\debug\jars\8000\40\org.apache.http.legacy-a5625a1aa7d1c0a0bf4647ee3b299ff643b51975.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\baseLibrary-2.3.3-575126a8f1a5e23f33dd35cbfae75ba6277fd82b.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\bolts-android-1.4.0-cf23b5aecaa32ac116c09a591456ec2b9e42b3a5.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\bolts-applinks-1.4.0-3475e9108a3c55eeacef5c88f0409e8ddd89b86d.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\bolts-tasks-1.4.0-f55924028f2bc01d44ad2113beb51e1d42b3cf98.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-02d7bfa32725032b20474ce5a6b496d11e6e3ab9.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-0cdbf3903582be9c20e6d4c6ceb71258c2cf53fe.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-0ee5c9d13af3d9b6d8a66c05b31b2817b66390b5.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-0fbdc4db187a1efff1e63757eaadf3931b4f5a87.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-19c73b5b04a450f4e11414e68458615daf323ebf.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-3082cc79371d023fca536a837c3afa147f37b391.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-336355207e78f1a537dc9f20a345e9818b9cce56.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-35ae90dafab9bdba84066aee3e0be830bcda3bde.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-38bbc1bb9daebddc77019b834bbc5cf799402a1b.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-3a0dc3a894d5b837a52559125db0d476f347b957.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-3d2f95057e110dff2a0d28b3d7b7bb2a6bd46e12.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-3e45f716057fc49266cc0564f385f5ca304f2f2c.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-3f317f01d2d7f52d8b466f3cda13243f91dd3704.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-40fadf721d24fb5023d494cc098300657eaa5f8a.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-46b51301cee189f52fdf050c0e603667a5697563.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-4cd8e75ad8ae9b323c978267293e8fc7701a8528.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-53dddb31f54df5620846c6bc2448a4a09ef36fc8.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-55905144b321036dc0b91f32d6a800649432ea73.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-5ec83367cbe14d0f508d81fc9173eb743614b0e3.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-5febb96f174b50afdc506c0b5172ac919d120b0f.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-69fa630a1d44f9347f5b66137f577b3d3ea72469.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-6d5b4f12c5f66b056a2b4abbd3852aa075dc7553.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-6e156584596ef04fb2471766571b7e38bdcd2bb6.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-86167172c5196083eff0324c88c3265eab25e942.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-8d1352e5c45862c25d03cc9ebb8251fe21bec24a.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-92d81d8dc5e9eff3e1419cd045d6111e99f43e16.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-995b7c34b8bf270882e1b471a3e4e1e6218aeeee.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-a3fe634443d8ac55e76e3f24c7b7afcaa58b8612.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-b95da7b4cabf89e692884d829130e6ad06e3797b.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-ba2a5adb0e06b0be1ecf375aeb88aff1085108db.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-bc9b955b32272b95710aaefe170067a66e93d7b3.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-c092b925f35b1adcc95209c9f5bb039cd150952c.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-c221fffbd4ed144883af15ac49b8ce5149719066.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-c4f602c13d703d8e86ffab0850d5e3dea008886c.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-c626b165d7a85eda864e83d50ce6d024ab7d9c10.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-d08cc52f1e99edfe7ba9ef94d3ab2a235e745579.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-d5e4c4f38c913bfc646d47e2b85b3de1c681b7cb.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-d9db5ab99d4b278bcfeaa6de1352c7dda412ccea.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-dcb4f6fe7c6343e4689963f3a4f4210681d7e23f.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-e15eaccb4b9e491228c25cb12db0e7cdf6de5c64.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-ef15299aa9367a4797ccdf9736e4f0c9a8d010cb.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-f65d9a0e2fbffa8b7440afb2db9d41cad9a969ff.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\classes-fcd7b43521f1c2cfdcb0f677afd951ec7fe85de3.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\common-1.0.0-d1aeaad741d6cb59bb5e7a3714cf946b24a1ebbc.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\common-1.0.0-d642f9f4e155adc6e4b5db9bc9b67051d8b05897.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\constraint-layout-solver-1.0.2-028d7ac4a13120fdf3ed1269cfc96c79f68cfa4b.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\converter-gson-2.2.0-0ad8a3e4a302c09e22dbd3e29c49809c966a2301.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\converter-jackson-2.2.0-d0e77747474fbe6d316527c59895b681cfaca927.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\core-3.3.0-9092f4db9d9485f49933e25764ad2ea66d119ee7.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\gson-2.7-f1d201ecb177163cf90eefadcf5c8ef7bf47f8b9.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\jackson-annotations-2.7.0-fe885ecd0b602fdc7e8e9c75db7fc161741d97f7.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\jackson-core-2.7.2-f436f0c959cd9014e7c45a3a4816a9487e85a53a.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\jackson-databind-2.7.2-95d4e0ff983ad3f13ee450cf8885a2d262a5608c.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\logging-interceptor-3.6.0-9f864054b8eb0df0deaadf99dd5accd779ac023d.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\okhttp-3.6.0-8ed3451ff436ef6dc933c0e03b57e153af038d0c.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\okio-1.11.0-b8f82bc44151f2c2231fc2a5ca98994b76f20228.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\renderscript-v8-ba89d33479cd991e1e1710220e218071fd616801.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\retrofit-2.2.0-0ab8c774bc0ac89db406aef4bb99f317a15d5d0b.jar --import C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preJackPackagedLibraries\debug\jars\8000\1f\support-annotations-27.0.1-efa02cb7839a17c71708c9cd7486e69446a1956b.jar --output-dex C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jack\debug\folders\1000\1f\main --output-jack C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\packaged\debug\classes.zip -D jack.import.type.policy=keep-first -D jack.import.resource.policy=keep-first --multi-dex legacy -D jack.java.source.version=1.8 -D jack.android.min-api-level=17 -D jack.annotation-processor.path=true -D jack.annotation-processor.path.list=C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\support-annotations\27.0.1\287742f1c6cea6d9126670e9f031890b0462362a\support-annotations-27.0.1.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.7.0\19f42c154ffc689f40a77613bc32caeb17d744e3\jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.parse.bolts\bolts-android\1.4.0\cc174c559b5177982887bf6e1b76003aebad9516\bolts-android-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.zxing\core\3.3.0\73c49077166faa4c3c0059c5f583d1d7bd1475fe\core-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.retrofit2\converter-gson\2.2.0\a09926806199499a20b2f5168779499abfa33342\converter-gson-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.retrofit2\converter-jackson\2.2.0\a8565d80d994f312b4f146de4d75f7626416a1f0\converter-jackson-2.2.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\googlecode\juniversalchardet\juniversalchardet\1.0.3\juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.databinding\baseLibrary\2.3.3\eb3399988a52099b0127e27fb5bed666eca86ace\baseLibrary-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okio\okio\1.11.0\840897fcd7223a8143f1d9b6f69714e7be34fd50\okio-1.11.0.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\common\1.0.0\e414a4cb28434e25c4f6aa71426eb20cf4874ae9\common-1.0.0.jar;C:\sdk-android\extras\m2repository\com\android\support\constraint\constraint-layout-solver\1.0.2\constraint-layout-solver-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.parse.bolts\bolts-applinks\1.4.0\8ad21bf21784dacce5f2043afb97218cc377e835\bolts-applinks-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.core\common\1.0.0\a2d487452376193fc8c103dd2b9bd5f2b1b44563\common-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.databinding\compiler\2.3.3\bf8a44e08f3f78c5cb5a782c36d57e9c63586549\compiler-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.gson\gson\2.7\751f548c85fa49f330cecbb1875893f971b33c4e\gson-2.7.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.7.2\8b8310381b690e317f5f0574e9b2dd7034778b4c\jackson-core-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.7.2\84ffa765dd258dbab8695963c41308b054f3a1cb\jackson-databind-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.parse.bolts\bolts-tasks\1.4.0\d85884acf6810a3bbbecb587f239005cbc846dc4\bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp3\logging-interceptor\3.6.0\81887458b69ddc32722df7e4c35235fd74e6a8ba\logging-interceptor-3.6.0.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.retrofit2\retrofit\2.2.0\41e67dba73c3347e4503761642c39d0e06ca1f2\retrofit-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.6.0\69edde9fc4b01c9fd51d25b83428837478c27254\okhttp-3.6.0.jar -D jack.annotation-processor.options=android.databinding.artifactType=APPLICATION,android.databinding.printEncodedErrors=1,android.databinding.minApi=17,android.databinding.isTestVariant=0,android.databinding.enableDebugLogs=0,android.databinding.sdkDir=C:\sdk-android,android.databinding.bindingBuildFolder=C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-compiler\debug,android.databinding.enableForTests=0,android.databinding.modulePackage=...,android.databinding.generationalFileOutDir=C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\bundles\debug\data-binding,android.databinding.xmlOutDir=C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-info\debug -D jack.annotation-processor.source.output=C:\project path\app\build\generated\source\apt\debug @C:\project path\app\build\intermediates\jack\debug\ecj-options.txt}

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
            jackInProcess false
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layouts/activities',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/fragments',
                            'src/main/res/layouts',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':p24lib')

//    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
//    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.2"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Comment: Jack has long been [deprecated](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html?imm_mid=0ef032&cmp=em-prog-na-na-newsltr_20170318)- don't use it anymore! Just use the newest Android Studio and you should be able to use Java8 features

Comment: I already have the last version of Android Studio Installed.

Comment: Then why do you still use the Jack compiler `jackOptions...`?

Comment: Everything works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need or want to manually edit `build.gradle`, here is what worked for me:

Drop Jack and upgrade to a sufficiently recent version of the Android Gradle plugin.

Java 8 support [was added in 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html), and 3.1.4 is the last version compatible with Gradle 4.4 (which comes bundled with Ubuntu 18.04). Jack is no longer needed and is now deprecated.

If you use Gradle Wrapper, run `./gradlew help` to see the current version. If you are on a version below 4.4, run `gradle wrapper` to upgrade Gradle Wrapper to your local Gradle version.

Your `build.gradle` is lacking the `buildscript` block which defines the Gradle plugin for Android—not sure if simply adding it will do the trick, YMMV.

Here are the changes I needed to make to my `build.gradle` (diff notation—drop lines starting with `-`, and add those starting with `+`):

```
+   buildscript {
+       repositories {
+           mavenCentral()
+           jcenter()
+           google()
+       }
+       dependencies {
+           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
+       }
+   }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
<...>
-           jackOptions {
-               enabled true
-               jackInProcess false
-           }
-           dexOptions {
-               javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
-           }
        }
<...>
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
-            maven {
-               url "https://maven.google.com"
-            }
+            maven()
+            google()
        }
    }
<...>
```